Which flow to allow front end to authenticate via Office but send credentials to node API to verify user?
I've added Office auth to the front end portal but am left wondering which process flow will allow the user to login to the web part via 365 but then somehow send that authentication to the back end node API (not part of office at all.)
To get/set cookies I imagine the user needs to auth to 365 but the callback needs to be my node API that can then set cookies back to the front end.
Which auth flow works in this case?  I can already call graph API from node for the user but want to replace the login entirely on the front end with Office auth.
